# How computed in Vue tracks it's dependencies under the hood?

Tags: vue.js, vue-reactivity

How Vue manages to track dependencies which are used for computed property(under the hood)? In react we have a list of dependencies, but in vue we provide just callback/getter function, how dependencies are extracted, how they tracked? I don't ask for exact implementation, just high level description of flow is ok.

Comment: Check "reactivity in depth" in both Vue 2 and 3 documentation, since they work differently

Answer (score 2):

The computed fn accpets a function called 'effect' as the first input parameter, this fn usually contains reactive obj like `ref()`

When the computed fn is executed, the effect fn will be marked as "activeEffect", then this effect will be executed, it will trigger the reading of reactive obj。 Reactive obj use Proxy as an interceptor for reading and writing, this "activeEffect" will be collected into is dependency collection thought Proxy. When the reactive obj change, these effect will be taken out and executed.